How do I change the order of my datapoints in ggplot?
I have specified a trait order for my ggplot, but it still seems to be putting Factor 2 above Factor 1 results. Is anyone able to help me change it over so Factor 1 is first?

Thank you!!!
# Calculate confidence intervals
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Lower_CI = B - 1.96 * SE,
         Upper_CI = B + 1.96 * SE)

# Extract Factor information from Trait column (formatted as sbp_f1, sbp_f2 etc)
data <- data %>%
  mutate(Factor = ifelse(grepl("_1$", Trait), "Factor 1", 
                         ifelse(grepl("_2$", Trait), "Factor 2", NA)),
         Trait = gsub("_1$|_2$", "", Trait))  # Use $ to ensure it matches at the end of the string

# Creating a numeric index for original order - this orders it by trait and then factor within trait level
data$Trait_order <- 1:nrow(data)

# Forest plot 
forest_plot <- ggplot(data, aes(x = B, y = reorder(Trait, -seq_along(Trait)), color = Factor)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(xmin = Lower_CI, xmax = Upper_CI), width = 0.0, position = position_dodge(width = 0.5)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-0.13, 0.13)) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "black") +  
  theme_minimal() 

Here is a text file of the dataframe:
examp_data = tibble::tribble(
  ~Trait,~SNPs,~B, ~SE, ~P,
  "SBP_1", 390, 0.006554091, 0.001747019, 0.000176,
  "SBP_2", NA, 0.001846634 , 0.000334887, 3.5e-08,
  "DBP_1", 382, 0.012876703, 0.003078088, 2.87e-05,
  "DBP_2", NA, 0.003288169, 0.000592373, 2.84e-08,
  "BMI_1", 466, 0.007422243, 0.02710709, 0.78422918,
  "BMI_2", NA, -0.003126531, 0.005006708, 0.5323201,
  "T1DM_1", 10, 0.003584794, 0.01773166, 0.8397845,
  "T1DM_2", NA, 0.001174186, 0.005017023, 0.81495358,
  "T2DM_1", 132, -0.006590517, 0.01234858, 0.5935446,
  "T2DM_2", NA, -0.00407231, 0.002266027, 0.07231746,
  "Ischemic stroke_1", 12, 0.22800446 ,0.10913808, 0.03669535,
  "Ischemic stroke_2", NA, 0.05281245, 0.01455551, 0.00028524,
  "Coronary artery disease_1", 50, -0.03303563, 0.02387137, 0.16638866,
  "Coronary artery disease_2", NA, 0.006239356, 0.004880509, 0.201100165,
  "Heart Failure_1", 8, 0.13261266, 0.05402584, 0.01410353,
  "Heart Failure_2", NA, 0.015389171, 0.01056498 ,0.1452211,
  "Atrial Fibrilation_1", 89, 0.02273494, 0.01612777, 0.1586352,
  "Atrial Fibrilation_2", NA, 0.001067058, 0.002704961, 0.6932254,
  "Smoking initiation_1", 74, 0.01544679 ,0.04423646, 0.726949,
  "Smoking initiation_2", NA, -0.00991767, 0.007405777, 0.180512,
  "Years of schooling_1", 271, -0.035986121, 0.04409166, 0.4144051,
  "Years of schooling_2", NA ,-0.007902512, 0.007425632, 0.2872287
)


It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's much easier to help with runnable code. Also remove anything not directly related to the problem like theme() and labs() which just add more noise to the code which makes it harder to see what's going on

The issue seems to be in the seq_along function being used. But proper help can be provided with some example input to test the code.

Thanks @Abinashbunty - I have now included the text file for my dataframe in the post. Cheers!

@Abinashbunty -Just to add, if i remove seq_along it makes no difference - e.g. if I put ggplot(data, aes(x = B, y = Trait_order, color = Factor)), factor 2 is still on top and it ignores my trait ordering. Cheers

Instead of position_dodge you can use position_dodge2 and set reverse = TRUE
library(tidyverse)


cleaned_data = examp_data |>
  mutate(lower_ci  = B - 1.96 * SE,
        upper_ci = B + 1.96 * SE,
        Factor = ifelse(grepl("_1$", Trait), "Factor 1", 
        ifelse(grepl("_2$", Trait), "Factor 2", NA)),
Trait = gsub("_1$|_2$", "", Trait))

cleaned_data$Trait_order = 1:nrow(cleaned_data)

ggplot(cleaned_data, aes(x = B,
                        y = reorder(Trait, -seq_along(Trait)),
                        color = Factor)) +
  geom_pointrange(aes(xmin = lower_ci,
                    xmax = upper_ci),
                    position = position_dodge2(width = 0.5, reverse = TRUE))


Created on 2024-07-17 with reprex v2.1.1

Absolute legend, thank you so much!

@emmyloo, if this solution answered your question, please consider upvoting it and marking it as the answer by selecting the check box near the upvote button.

You can often change the display order of a categorical group by casting it as a factor, and reordering the factor. Here, the natural ordering of {Factor 1, Factor 2} results in a plot that's backwards from how you'd like, so just reverse the factor ordering before calling the plotting function:
data$Factor = factor(data$Factor, levels = c("Factor 2", "Factor 1"))

This approach is handy since it doesn't require any knowledge of the plotting function parameters - it changes the actual data piped into the plotting function, rather than using the plotting function itself to display it differently. As an additional benefit, this would allow you to reorder plots with more than two factor levels into any ordering you like, as opposed to just reversing the default order.
Note that this will apply the same color order to the reordered elements (so Factor 1 will now be in blue instead of red as in the original plot).
